# Spring 4.0.0M2: Can't find Spring.jar file.

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring 4.0.0M2, in this I didn't find the `Spring.jar` file.

Can anyone let me know where I can find the `Spring.jar` file in Spring 4.0.0M2.

Comment: I would also suggest you to surf the spring blogs http://www.springsource.org/get-started

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Maven Project, then use this repository and maven coordinates. It will download all the dependencies for you.

Repository -

```
http://repo.springsource.org/milestone/
```

Maven co-ordinates

```
<dependency>  
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
</dependecy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spring versions released after 2.5, all the modules are not released as a single jar. This  might be due to the growing size of the framework and at the same time giving the user freedom of choosing what they want.

You can download the complete bundle, but it will contain separate jars for each module. Like spring-core, spring-aop, spring-beans, spring-jdbc etc.